# A parallel system functions whenever at least one of its components works.

Tags: probability, statistics

A parallel system functions  whenever at least one of its components works. Consider a system  of  3 components and suppose that each  component independently  works with probability  0.40.  Find the probability that the component  1 works  given that  the system is functioning.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you demonstrate that you've made a serious attempt to do the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts on it?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: You can apply the Bayes theorem. The relevant events are:

$F: \texttt{"Component 1 works"}$ and $S: \texttt{"System is functioning"}$

$$P(\texttt{F|S})=\frac{P(F\cap S )}{P(S)}$$

$F\cap S $ is the event when the system is functioning and component 1 works. Thus you need all combinations of components where at least component 1 works. These combinations are $(1,2,3);(1,2,\overline 3), (1, \overline 2, 3); (1, \overline 2, \overline 3)$

*The line over the letters/numbers indicates that the corresponding component/system does not work.*

And for $P(S)$ you can use the converse probability. It makes the calculation much simpler. $P(S)=1-P(\overline S)$